# Loading more data inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have added scrollview inside UITableViewCell, now i have to add Show More Info button inside the scrollview at the bottom . When user clicks on 'show more info' requests has to be sent to server and the parsed response has to be shown in scrollview, appending to the old data in cell/scrollview. I think i can use reload table view once i get response from server but this will scroll the scrollview to top.
What is the best way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reload row:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathToReload] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: This seems to be scrolling the scrollview to top.

Comment: You can remember position of the scrollView before the update and after update scroll scrollView to current position: [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:NO];